# Add Adsense code between job listings - wp job manager plugin

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, adsense

I am using the [wp-job-manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/) and i want to add an Adsense code between the job listings ( after fifth job listing ) in the page with [jobs] shortcode.

The function that outputs the jobs resides in [`class-wp-job-manager-shortcodes.php`](https://github.com/Automattic/WP-Job-Manager/blob/master/includes/class-wp-job-manager-shortcodes.php) **function `output_jobs( $atts )`**

Because i don't know how to start to add that Adsense code to this function using action hooks or what else i need some help to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

There's a filter for the output

```
    $job_listings_output = apply_filters( 'job_manager_job_listings_output', ob_get_clean() );
```

so, you should just do

```
add_filter('job_manager_job_listings_output','my_job_manager_job_listings_output');
function my_job_manager_job_listings_output($output) {
   $adsense_code = ' My adsense code';
   return $output . $adsence_code;
}
```

Comment: @cjbj Thank you for your reply. You give me a start point. Now i have to find a way to put the code after the fifth job listing. That should do it before $adsense_code variable;

Comment: You'd have to parse the `$job_listings_output` to put the adsense code exactly where you need it. Shouldn't be difficult

Comment: user1049961 thank you for your help. For me it seems to be difficult i am afraid. I am trying to put all these together but i need more help. I am searching and try to understand your response.

Comment: Sorry, but no one is going to write the code for you for free. You should try to do something yourself  and ask for advice,  or hire a developer

Comment: I know that i am just searching and looking for help to make this working. Otherwise if i know how to do it  i won't ask anything anywhere..i am just trying to understand something that i am learning now

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, afaik you cannot get "every nth occurance", so i just used explode/implode. I had to do it twice, because my jobs get loaded by ajax too and there is another filter for that:

```
add_filter('job_manager_job_listings_output', function ($output) {
    $adsense_code = 'xxx';
    $temp_result_exploded = explode('</li>', $output);
    $temp_result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp_result_exploded); $i++) {
        $temp_result[] = $temp_result_exploded[$i];
        if ($i % 5 === 0 && $i > 0) {
            $temp_result[] = '<li>' . $adsense_code;
        }
    }
    return implode('</li>', $temp_result);
});

add_filter('job_manager_get_listings_result', function($result, $jobs) {
    $adsense_code = 'xxx';
    $temp_result_exploded = explode('</li>', $result['html']);
    $temp_result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($temp_result_exploded); $i++) {
        $temp_result[] = $temp_result_exploded[$i];
        if ($i % 5 === 0 && $i > 0) {
            $temp_result[] = '<li>' . $adsense_code;
        }
    }
    $result['html'] = implode('</li>', $temp_result);
    return $result;
}, 10, 2);
```

Of course there is some redundant code, but this is just an example :)